# Spring Boot Rest Controller - Selection of route

Tags: java, spring, rest, routes

Trying to figure out why the rest controller selected a certain route...

```
@RestController
public class BookingController {

  // other code

  @GetMapping("/bookings/time={startTime}&{endTime}")
      public List<Booking> getBookingsDuringTime(@PathVariable String startTime,
                                               @PathVariable String endTime) {
      // function code
  }

  @GetMapping("/bookings/{bookingId}")
  public Booking getBookingById(@PathVariable long bookingId) {
      // function code
  }
```

When I sent a post request to the route  "/bookings/time=2020-10-11T18:00:00.00&2020-10-11T21:00:00.00" it would try to route the request through getBookingById. This threw an exception for an invalid parameter type.

I modified so that

```
@GetMapping("/bookings/{bookingId}")
```

became

```
@GetMapping("/bookings/id={bookingId}")
```

then the program responded as expected, routing the request through getBookingsDuringTime and returning the correct information.

Comment: Were you escaping the `&` correctly?

Comment: Yes, I tried escaping the `&` with `%26`. It was only when I changed the /bookings/{bookingId} mapping that it worked, even without modifying other time mapping.

Comment: I suggest setting your log level for `org.springframework.web` to `DEBUG` and examining the startup messages. It will explain exactly what routes are detected, including information such as expected parameters, content types, etc.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your rest url are incorrect from the start... I would have done as :

```
  @GetMapping("/bookings")
  public List<Booking> getBookingsDuringTime(@RequestParam String startTime,
                                           @RequestParam  String endTime) {
  // function code
  }

  @GetMapping("/bookings/{bookingId}")
  public Booking getBookingById(@PathVariable long bookingId) {
      // function code
  }
```

and you would have call the `getBookingsDuringTime` as

```
/bookings?startTime=XXX&endTime=XXX
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! There are other ways I implemented to search the bookings by, such as by date, only start time, etc.. Does the rest controller allow you to have multiple GetMappings to the same route, but with different request parameters?

Comment: Did a little more research into this, it works if params are specified in the mapping. Such as : `@GetMapping(value = '/bookings, params = {"startTime", "endTime"}'`. Thanks again @storm_buster.

Comment: No, I strongly you suggest to have one url. and all search parameter as request param. and in your service you can manage what request param are null and act accordingly. If you have too much request param.... consider a POST url like `bookings/search`  and a request body with all your search creteria